# Cmdlet parameter type to select a parameter set

Tags: c#, powershell

Using c# to write a PowerShell cmdlet that has several parameter sets.

Is there a parameter Type that can be used to qualify/select the required set?

For instance suppose I have these sets of parameters for a Create-IceCream cmdlet:

```
Create-IceCream [-Choco] .. <insert Choco specific parameters here>

Create-IceCream [-Cherry] .. <insert Cherry specific parameters here>

Create-IceCream .. <insert plain specific parameters here>
```

What would be the Type for parameters "Choco" and "Cherry"? Obviously a SwitchParameter type can't be used since it can still be specified with $false value.

An Enum type would not be so intuitive and will require me to create many dynamic parameters.

Any ideas? And I probably should've mentioned that for this question let's assume I'm restricted to creating one cmdlet only.

Thanks,

Comment: Come again why switch can't be used?

Comment: Cuz I think something like "Create-IceCream -Choco:$false" wouldn't make sense. It will invoke the "Choco" set, with no "Choco". Do you get it? I guess what I'm after is a true switch parameter, one that be either not-present or present. Just like in regular console type commands. Unlike microsoft's SwitchParameter which can be not-present, present:$true, or present:$false.

Comment: You don't have to create a switch parameter in this case. All you need is two different parametersets with whatever type you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have parameters that are truly unique between sets, then you don't need a "selector" parameter at all.  The "operable" params specified will determine the set on their own.  This is the recommended approach, and the way most cmdlets work.

Sometimes it does make it a bit clearer for the user to provide such a parameter, though.  `Switch` is your best option for this, despite your worries.  ParameterSets work entirely by the **existence** of parameters, they are totally ignorant of the **value** of any specified params. As such, there is no totally perfect option of any type.  `Switch` provides the simplest interface available.

Users have to be trying pretty hard to mess this up by passing `-Choco:$false`, considering the 99% usage of switch parameters is simple present/not-present.  And powershell will enforce the parameterset either way, so it's not possible to pass both `-Choco:$false -Cherry:$true`.

In my experience, very few users even realize you can pass an explicit value to a `Switch`, and those who do tend to be more experienced and wouldn't make that kind of mistake anyway.

**Edit**

Another option is to have a single `-IceCreamType` parameter which takes either an `Enum` or a string with `ValidateSet`.  It can be a mandatory parameter that is part of all parametersets.  Then internally you can interpret remaining shared args as needed.  Powershell will complain, however, if it can't figure out the parameter set based on the args passed, so there is some danger with this approach.  You could work around with a `DefaultParameterSetName`, but after all of this you are starting to lose the value of using parametersets in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have is that all the required parameters in those different sets are not unique, though the underlying/corresponding code is completely different. Unique parameters on the other hand are optional! I guess there's no such parameter with null or non-null/present nature.

Comment: Seems SwitchParameter is the closest I can get. You're right, I can just test for HasValue and just ignore the underlying boolean value. I was just thinking there might be a more 'elegant' type of parameter.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Will accept your answer. About using an Enum type. I didn't want to do that for the reasons you mentioned. I also thought about decorating the switch parameter with an ArgumentTransformation attribute, which would write and error for $false, but that, besides still being counter-intuitive, is an overkill! I wonder why microsoft chose to implement a SwitchParameter in this way since you can achieve the same thing with an optional Nullable boolean parameter. Anyway ..

Comment: Switches need to be explicitly settable in order to enable **programmatic** specification.  e.g. your script needs to do a `dir`, but based on the results of previous computation it might need to recurse, or it might not.  You can call `dir -Recurse:$needToRecurse` instead of `if($needToRecurse){ dir -Recurse }else{ dir }`.  I agree this is a different scenario than yours, but we've only got one switch type so we gotta work with it :)